# Getting cronjob to run PHP script as PHP5

Tags: php, cron

I am using 1and1 hosting and trying to run a cronjob using PHP5. For some reason, the cron is using PHP4.. even though the global PHP version on site is PHP5.

The script works fine in a browser, but gives me errors when SSHing and directly running the file. The reason I know it's using PHP4 is because it says "X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9"

The cron looks like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php
```

I'm thinking it's gotta be something related to the php path. Any ideas?

Comment: You could ask 1&1 what the path to their PHP5 executable is. (At that occasion, ask them why they are still running PHP4) (not my downvote though)

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin/php5` yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `/usr/bin/php5` ?

That's a common location for PHP 5.

Comment: thats it - thanks. this was a dumb question but i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to do

`* * * * * php /path/to/file.php5`

I don't use the opening line to run php. Maybe this is sloppy? But try renaming the file with a .php5 extension and just adding "php " before the path in the cron manager.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
* * * * * php -q  /path/to/file.php
```